# To get the index of the TR

Tags: javascript

I need to find out the position of the TR.

Actually, I got the index of the TD which is 291,
But I need to get the index of the TR contains the TD.

We can get the `innerHTML` by

```
document.getElementsByTagName("td")[291].parentNode.innerHTML..
```

How to get the index of that `parentNode` I mean the TR.

Please help me

Answer (score 2):

```
var parent = document.getElementsByTagName("td")[291].parentNode;
var index = -1;
for (var i = 0; i < parent.childNodes.length; i++) {
  if (parent.childNodes.item(i) == tr) {
    index = i;
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering why you need the index of that node ?

You can assign

var trNode = document.getElementsByTagName("td")[291].parentNode;

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example...

http://www.maratz.com/blog/archives/2005/05/18/detect-table-row-index-with-javascript/